# What does this piece of code? What is the purpose?

Tags: c

My homework is this piece of code and I need the explanation and output. I can't understand what this code does and what is the output can anyone help me to understand thanks.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
 int x = 10;
```

Comment: Try to compile this first, and then execute.

Comment: I did but without '{ }' this code wont work and if I add those by myself ı couldnt understand what does this code do .

Comment: If the code behaves differently with and without `{` braces `}` there is something you have not shown, which, as it is not a complete program, there is.

Comment: Are you sure this is all the code? Because this code does nothing and has no output.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès no, it's correct (but pointless) C code once put into a function.

Comment: What makes you think there is any output, given the complete and utter absence of output-generating functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code iterates 10 times over the variable `i` from `i=0` to `i=9` with a `for` loop. For every iteration, it declares the variable `x` as an integer and assign it the value of `10`. This code has no output.

**Edit after the comment:** if you do not use `{}` the code has no problem in this case, because in the `for` loop there is only one instruction. This:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    int x = 10;
```

and this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int x = 10;
}
```

are the same because there's only one instruction

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should notice is the syntax
`for`,`if` and `while` execute the next block or statement, if there is no block.

so your code is the same as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int x = 10;
}
```

With this formatting and in a block it is easier to see what it does.

Since the x variable is declared and assigned within the body of the loop and not visible to the out side. Nothing useful comes out of assigning it 10 times, an optimizing compiler could remove the entire block.